# Disabling Alt L from going to the File/Edit/View menu (within TeXstudio)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, latex

I want to create various keyboard shortcuts within TeXstudio, but my problem is that the left Alt key takes me out of the text editor and into the File/Edit/View menus (so I can navigate around these menus with the arrow keys). If I press Alt L again, I return to the text editor. How can I disable Alt L from doing this, so that I can use e.g. Alt+a for \alpha, and so on? Thank you.

Comment: Then you will have the issue of not being able to access the menus.  Wouldn't it be better to set your keyboard shortcuts using, for instance, the super key (i.e., the flag key).

Comment: Presumably I would still be able to access the menus with the cursor? I only want to disable the Alt L shortcut for the menus.

Comment: If I wanted to use the super key instead, how do I disable its default action of bringing up the search menu in the top left?

Comment: By not releasing the button.  That is, you press the <kbd>SUPER</kbd> key and, while pressed, you press <kbd>A</kbd>.  If you press <kbd>SUPER</kbd> and then let go it produces the action you mention.  In my case, since I do not have <kbd>SUPER</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> assigned, then it is taken as only <kbd>SUPER</kbd> being pressed.  Once you assign the shortcut it should work.

Comment: I can't even assign such a shortcut because the menu is immediately brought up once I press the super key...

Comment: Try this SUPER + W (at the same time).  It should immediately bring the open application selector.  If, however, you do SUPER and wait for a while and then it will put numbers to the applications on the icons on the menu.  If you press and then immediately release SUPER then the behaviour should be as you explained, it bringing up the Dash.